# Does Visual Studio 2010 express prevents Source Controls plugins?

Tags: git, visual-studio, plugins

I try to install this plugin on my Visual Studio 2010 Express : http://gitscc.codeplex.com/

But I can't find it in the plugin repository, the "Source Control" category of plugins is empty, is that normal ? Does the Express edition prevent utilization of Source Controls plugins ?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's [a list of things that are missing from the express versions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikhailarkhipov/archive/2006/06/26/647516.aspx). Source control is there, I'm afraid.

Comment: Also, do you know if the professionnal edition will supports this plugin ? Or do I need a (expensive) version that supports TFS ?

Comment: The express version isn't for professional work, and as far as Microsoft are concerned, hobbyists don't need source control :-)

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a reference right now, but the Express editions do not allow you to install any plugins at all.

Comment: Its not more the case with VS2010 :)