# Visual Studio 2010 express with TFS 2012 express.

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I want to use Visual Studio 2010 express with TFS 2012 express. I installed the prereq's for VS and then installed TFS. when I look for Tools-> Options-> Source Control it had disappeared there is no option to add the solution when I right click on it or when I create a new one. Can any one point me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: Start Here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34673

Comment: Answered here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904350/does-visual-studio-2010-express-prevents-source-controls-plugins .  And no, express doesn't have tfsvc source control.